# Showing a search bar based on the options in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a dropdown button (with Bootstrap) that shows different actions.

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Find on search bar 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Find on search bar 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Find on search bar 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I also have 3 possible search bars:

```
<div class="form-inline" >
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 1">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 2">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 3">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Now every search bar is linked to another search engine and the script for handling the input in each search bar is as follow:

```
<script>
      const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
      const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
      const site = '...';
        
      searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {const url = site + searchInput.value;
      const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
              });
</script>
```

But I want to try to tie it all together, so the idea is that I have a dropdown that specifies each search engine and when a search engine is selected, it shows one of the three search bars on the screen, with a default search engine. So it shows one of these three (with one that is the default):

```
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 1">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 2">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 3">
```

So the process flow on the screen will be something as follow:

1. You see a default search bar and a dropdown button;
2. You select a search engine from the dropdown list;
3. The search bar changes to the search bar that is linked to the dropdown item that is selected.

Does anyone have an idea for doing this or did someone do this before?

Comment: One problem at first look, you can't have the same ID for more than 1 element, so you need to give each search bar a different ID.

Comment: Yes, indeed. but the main confusion is how to get the item selected to show a different element.

Answer (score 0):

One possible flow:

Give each search input a different ID. Use this same id as a `data-id` attribute on the respective `dropdown-item`. So it looks like:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-id="search-input-1">Find on search bar 1</a>

<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input-1" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search bar 1">
```

So now, you can use a `click` event on the `dropdown-item` to get the `data-id`, and hence which search input should be shown. You can store which input is currently visible in a value, and change it upon every time a dropdown-item is clicked. And then use your search button as you're already doing, but using this saved value.

You can see here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/wzkrv361/16/)